# Refactoring potentially complex template

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Let supplier be documents (with code, names, and many other fields).
I have a component

```
export class SuppliersDetails  extends MeteorComponent {
  supplier: any;
  invalidKeys: Object; // array <key> => <error message>
```

and a form

```
 <div>
     <input [(ngModel)]="supplier.code" [class.invalid]="invalidKeys['code']" id="code" type="text" class="validate">
     <label for="code" [class.active]="supplier.code || invalidKeys['name']" [attr.data-error]="invalidKeys['code']" >Code</label>
 </div>
```

that allow me to edit it.

**How could I refactore my component/template, to lighten my template ?**

Here it's only 1 field, and only the display of invalidKeys message is handled. But I have 8 fields and some specific logic to add. This will get unreadable.

I am looking for something like

```
<div>
    <input plsDoItAllAndUseThatId='code'></input>
    <label plsDoItAllAndUseThatId='code'>Code</input>
</div>
```

But I have no idea of the design, any idea ?

Comment: There isn't much you can do. You can wrap it in a component but using a custom component as form input fields (with `[(ngModel)]="..."`) isn't trivial either. It needs to implement `ControlValueAccessor` and it needs to be configurable in case some things are varying between inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [dynamic forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) as described in the cookbook section of angular2 docs. The key here is to separate the business logic out of the form itself, such as by creating:

- A questions object that will hold all the input properties
- A service that will create all the generate all the questions needed by a specific form
- A generic component that will loop through a list of questions and bind all the question properties to the input

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good time you could use an attribute directive.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#write-directive

You could write it as an attribute like you did in what you want to do. With that you can manipulate the element in the directive to add other attributes if you want or do whatever.

That would make it pretty slick. I'm a fan of this kind of stuff.

Lots of cool stuff you can do with that if you get creative.

Comment: I do like the solution.
_[class.active]="supplier.code || invalidKeys['name']" [attr.data-error]="invalidKeys['code']"_

Is there any way I keep the same syntax to do my logic, or am I obliged to go with oldschool dom element manipulation to set styles and classes ? (Manipulating a ElementRef)